# TimeoutException after facebook login when using securesocial module in play 2.0.2

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm using securesoial 2.9.1, 2.0.6 version with play 2.0.2. I'm getting a promise timeout exception while redirecting after successful login via facebook to a particular url.

the url is specified in the routes file and that url is written in the `securesocial.conf` file as written below:

```
onLoginGoTo=/after-redirect
```

full stack trace is :

```
[debug] application - authorizationUrl = https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize
[debug] application - Redirecting to : [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email&client_id=XYZ&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flab.verchaska.com%2Ftest%2Fauthenticate%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&state=ab113e0b-37cc-4849-b84e-a84a5fe7f135]
[error] application -

! @6cd55ef0a - Internal server error, for request [GET /test/authenticate/facebook?state=ab113e0b-37cc-4849-b84e-a84a5fe7f135&code=AQDkiVlAMuutA5KEt1fA17fFUjh1RSQJ7MpLwlyfr10PK35izqZq5JXTgWQhIvpQv7GwrK5iMBz_VjpIRd9Qy784YczSZjudgHKTj1M3DOjRZAg5le1wHeWqwClQ4isZf9oRcmPVuswxG8uvTSQNZzUEjrAQZ5tQ0o67N5Xp0kc2kAjJKnf906nFaTmllYAgTP_D92fkI6fhGuVkDVrlnkiB] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[TimeoutException: Promise timed out after 10000 : MILLISECONDS]]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Promise timed out after 10000 : MILLISECONDS
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$await$1.apply(Promise.scala:158) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$await$1.apply(Promise.scala:154) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
        at scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.InTxnImpl.runBlock(InTxnImpl.scala:538) ~[scala-stm_2.9.1.jar:0.5]
        at scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.InTxnImpl.topLevelAttempt(InTxnImpl.scala:494) ~[scala-stm_2.9.1.jar:0.5]
        at scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.InTxnImpl.topLevelAtomicImpl(InTxnImpl.scala:365) ~[scala-stm_2.9.1.jar:0.5]
        at scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.InTxnImpl.atomic(InTxnImpl.scala:244) ~[scala-stm_2.9.1.jar:0.5]
```

I have my own domain, I'm not using localhost:9000.

Comment: Do you see anything else on the logs? I don't see any of SecureSocial classes in that stack trace. Any chance your internet connection was having issues at that time?

Comment: @Jorge No, I have been trying this out since last 1 week and the internet connection is working fine, no issues at all. Nothing related to SecureSocial comes in that stack trace.

Comment: @Jorge I got it solved, was a proxy issue. :-/